# Rails: `model.each { |x| x.destroy }` in `around_destroy` not working the same as elswhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, destroy

I have a many-to-many relationship between `ModelA` and `ModelB`, and I want all of `ModelB` to be destroyed if its associated `ModelA` is destroyed.

So my `model_a.rb` has an `around_destroy` like this:

```
around_destroy :destroy_model_bs

def destroy_model_bs
  m_bs = self.model_bs
  yield
  m_bs.each {|m_b| m_b.destroy }
end
```

But this simply destroys the association.

However, in the console, if I do the exact same thing:

```
m_a  = ModelA.find(104) # 104 being the ID
m_bs = m_a.model_bs
m_bs.each {|m_b| m_b.destroy }
```

This actually destroys all of the ModelBs associated with the ModelA with ID 104.

Why is this happening? And, if possible, let me know of a better way to destroy all (`dependent: :destroy` does not work with many-to-many).

Answer (score 0):

Is your relationship `habtm`? You might be better off creating a join table using `has_many through`. Then you could use `dependent: :destroy`.

Comment: It’s a direct many-to-many relationship, not an indirect `has_many through: :model_b` relationship. But even if I were to change it to `has_many through:`, I’m still curious to know why this is behaving the way it is.

For the moment, I just did it in `before_destroy` and it works fine.

Comment: I'm not sure why the `around_destroy` isn't working. Have you tried it as a `before_destroy` callback?

Comment: I did. My previous comment: “For the moment, I just did it in `before_destroy` and it works fine.” I’m gonna play around with it to figure it out and post a solution here if I find one.